# How to disable this window in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

When i try to put breakpoints in any of my files, suddenly this window pops up. Whatever I try, its not letting me continue the operations? What is this? And how can I disable this window?

[image]

Comment: Are these overloaded methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double click on any break point then you will get one window in that window select all break points(command+A) then press delete key.

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling all breakpoints. Just click on "Breakpoints" button and this disables all of them.